# Simple cycled slideshow with next/prev link

Tags: jquery, jquery-animate, slideshow, cycle

I am more or less a beginner to Jquery and to start with it
I tried to make a clickable, cycled slideshow, based on [this](http://jonraasch.com/blog/a-simple-jquery-slideshow) one.
So far so good. The code works (see below).
My questions:

1. Isn't there an easier way to write the code. I am kind of repeating the same code for prev and next.
2. When I click on the next/prev links and the animation starts — and during the animation I click again, then sometimes the image is flickering or there is an error.
   Is there a way to force the animation to finish, before it reacts on my click.

Javascript:

```
    $(function() {

    $('#prev').click(function() {
        var $active = $('#slideshow IMG.active');
        var $prev = $active.prev();
        $active.addClass('last-active');

    if($active.is(":first-child")){$prev = $("IMG:last-child");}
        $prev.css({opacity: 0.0})
            .addClass('active')
            .animate({opacity: 1.0}, 1000, function() {
                $active.removeClass('active last-active');
            }); 

    }); 


    $('#next').click(function() {
        var $active = $('#slideshow IMG.active');
        var $next = $active.next();
        $active.addClass('last-active');

    if($active.is(":last-child")){$next = $("IMG:first-child");}
        $next.css({opacity: 0.0})
            .addClass('active')
            .animate({opacity: 1.0}, 1000, function() {
                $active.removeClass('active last-active');
            }); 

    }); 

    });
```

CSS:

```
    #slideshow {position:relative; height:350px; opacity:1.0;}
    #slideshow IMG {position:absolute; top:0; left:0; z-index:8; opacity:0.0;}
    #slideshow IMG.active {z-index:10; opacity:1.0;}
    #slideshow IMG.last-active {z-index:9;}
    #next {color:#0000ff; cursor:pointer;}
    #prev {color:#0000ff; cursor:pointer;}
```

HTML:

```
    <div id="slideshow">
        <img src="image1.jpg" class="active" />
        <img src="image2.jpg" />
        <img src="image3.jpg" />
        <img src="image4.jpg" />
    </div>
    <div id="next">NEXT</div>
    <div id="prev">PREV</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

http://jsfiddle.net/kPD4n/

There you go.

1) Add the same class for "NEXT" and "PREV" buttons, and then check which is clicked.
2) Added .stop(0,1) to jump to end of animation.

Still a little buggy though...

Comment: Very cool, Thank you!
– I guess console.log is just there to test, right?
– I don't understand exactly, what the (0,1) stands for in stop(), even though I read http://api.jquery.com/stop/

Comment: First 0 means that the animation queue is not cleared, so if you trigger 10 times the animation, the animation will perform 10 times (full-length). And thus if you click fast the next button 10 times you will have to wait for all the animations to end. The second '1' is to stop the curent animation you are playing (actual finish the curent animation). So if you press 10 times the next button, the first 9 times the animation will be instantly-done and only the last animation will be shown. .stop(0,1) is the usual way to solve this repeating animation problem.

Comment: Note that with stop(0,1) even if the queue is not cleared no animation is added to the queue because when you click the trigger button while the animation is playing it will finish that animation and simply perform this one.

Answer (score 1):

Well everytime I come accross the need of building some cycle stuff, i utilize the [jQuery Cycle PlugIn](http://jquery.malsup.com/cycle/). This may not be the answer to you optimization question, but I think everyone should have taken a look at the Cycle plugin.

And as you can see [here on the demo page](http://jquery.malsup.com/cycle/int2.html) you can make use of next/prev buttons very easy, too. Just like

```
$('#slideshow').cycle({ 
    fx:     'fade', 
    speed:  'fast', 
    timeout: 0, 
    next:   '#next', 
    prev:   '#prev' 
});
```

And your HTML code can stay that way.

Comment: Thank you! I know the cycle plugin. But to learn about Jquery, I wanted to build it myself. And I just couldn't manage to center the cylce-plugin vertically AND horizontally. There must be something in the Plugin-code, that makes that hard...